# In Excel file , How to set cell name using Java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have an excel file. I want to set a unique name to a particular cell.
But there is no method called "cell.setName".

Answer (score 3):

**Regarding official documentation:**

Named Range is a way to refer to a group of cells by a name. Named Cell is a degenerate case of Named Range in that the 'group of cells' contains exactly one cell. You can create as well as refer to cells in a workbook by their named range. When working with Named Ranges, the classes org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference and org.apache.poi.ss.util.AreaReference are used.

Note: Using relative values like 'A1:B1' can lead to unexpected moving of the cell that the name points to when working with the workbook in Microsoft Excel, usually using absolute references like '$A$1:$B$1' avoids this, see also this discussion.

```
Creating Named Range / Named Cell

    // setup code
    String sname = "TestSheet", cname = "TestName", cvalue = "TestVal";
    Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet(sname);
    sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue(cvalue);

    // 1. create named range for a single cell using areareference
    Name namedCell = wb.createName();
    namedCell.setNameName(cname + "1");
    String reference = sname+"!$A$1:$A$1"; // area reference
    namedCell.setRefersToFormula(reference);

    // 2. create named range for a single cell using cellreference
    Name namedCel2 = wb.createName();
    namedCel2.setNameName(cname + "2");
    reference = sname+"!$A$1"; // cell reference
    namedCel2.setRefersToFormula(reference);

    // 3. create named range for an area using AreaReference
    Name namedCel3 = wb.createName();
    namedCel3.setNameName(cname + "3");
    reference = sname+"!$A$1:$C$5"; // area reference
    namedCel3.setRefersToFormula(reference);

    // 4. create named formula
    Name namedCel4 = wb.createName();
    namedCel4.setNameName("my_sum");
    namedCel4.setRefersToFormula("SUM(" + sname + "!$I$2:$I$6)");
```

Link: https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NamedRanges

Comment: You should include the link to the documentation

Answer (score 0):

```
// setup code
String sname = "TestSheet", cname = "TestName", cvalue = "TestVal";
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet(sname);
sheet.createRow(0).createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(cvalue);

// 1. create named range for a single cell using areareference
Name namedCell = wb.createName();
namedCell.setNameName(cname);
String reference = sname+"!A1:A1"; // area reference
namedCell.setRefersToFormula(reference);
```

From : http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NamedRanges